# How do you use Flowable.generate from Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2, kotlin-interop

Here's a failed stub attempt at Flowable.generate (with more type annotations than I'd normally use):

```
val xs: Flowable<String> = Flowable.generate<Int, String>(
  java.util.concurrent.Callable<Int> { -> 0 },
  io.reactivex.functions.BiConsumer<Int, String> { t1, t2 -> }
)
```

The Java signature I'd like to use is:

```
public static <T, S> Flowable<T> generate(Callable<S> initialState, final BiConsumer<S, Emitter<T>> generator)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error:(145, 12) None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
@CheckReturnValue @BackpressureSupport @SchedulerSupport public final fun <T : Any!, S : Any!> generate(p0: (() -> (???..???))!, p1: (((???..???), Emitter<(???..???)>!) -> Unit)!): Flowable<(???..???)>! defined in io.reactivex.Flowable
@CheckReturnValue @BackpressureSupport @SchedulerSupport public final fun <T : Any!, S : Any!> generate(p0: (() -> (???..???))!, p1: ((???, Emitter<(???..???)>) -> ???)!): Flowable<(???..???)>! defined in io.reactivex.Flowable
@CheckReturnValue @BackpressureSupport @SchedulerSupport public open fun <T : Any!, S : Any!> generate(p0: Callable<(???..???)>!, p1: BiConsumer<(???..???), Emitter<String!>!>!): Flowable<String!>! defined in io.reactivex.Flowable
@CheckReturnValue @BackpressureSupport @SchedulerSupport public open fun <T : Any!, S : Any!> generate(p0: Callable<Int!>!, p1: BiFunction<Int!, Emitter<(???..???)>!, Int!>!): Flowable<(???..???)>! defined in io.reactivex.Flowable
```

What *should* I be feeding the compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type for `generate()` should be `<String, Int>` and the type for `BiConsumer` should be `<Int, Emitter<String>>`.

```
val xs: Flowable<String> = Flowable.generate<String, Int>(
        java.util.concurrent.Callable<Int> { -> 0 },
        io.reactivex.functions.BiConsumer<Int, Emitter<String>> { t1, t2 ->  }
)
```

Comment: I would have sworn I triple-checked the order of the type parameters, but obviously not.